# Trying to make flex container row, but not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the div that has 2 divs inside him into a flex-container row.

But flex is not working for some reason.

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="project-section">
    <div class="flex-projects-1">
        <p>Website</p>
        <h2>A website about hearing care for children</h2>
        <p>I built the site for the company I worked for,
            The site was built through the WordPress platform,
            through a clean template
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-projects-2">
        <p>test123</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.projects-section {
    display: flex;
}

.projects-section,
p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.projects-section,
h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-projects-2 p {
    border: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
}
```

**Screenshot of how it looks like at the moment:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a spell mistake in `projects-section` class. You have wrote `projects-section` in css and `project-section` in html. Rename it either in css or in html.

After correcting name and applying `background-color: black` (you can remove this background color as per your requirement) .

```css
.project-section {
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
}

.projects-section,
p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.projects-section,
h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.flex-projects-2 p {
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-section">
  <div class="flex-projects-1">
    <p>Website</p>
    <h2>A website about hearing care for children</h2>
    <p>I built the site for the company I worked for, The site was built through the WordPress platform, through a clean template
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-projects-2">
    <p>test123</p>
  </div>
</div>
```